# Replacement Bathroom Downlight

Tags: bathroom, led

We had a new bathroom installed a few years ago.  It has four LED downlight and, over time, the lights have all burned out.  I replaced one of the lights a few years ago, but can't remember what type of light I bought.  As I recall, the light came with a bezel and mounting hardware and various other bits, none of which I needed.  It seemed like a huge waste.

The light fixture has numbers on it (10w WW 36°) as does the cable, but nothing that I've been able to use to find a replacement.

The lights are on the bathroom ceiling and are recessed, with a small chrome bezel.  Two of them are near - if not above - the shower.  I assume they need to be IP65.  We are in the UK.  I went to Screwfix today but they were not able to help me - they couldn't show me any lights, I had to buy them and return them (Covid restrictions).  I have also googled this extensively but I have not seen any lights like this.

I would like to know what type of light this is - what I need to buy, and whether or not every time I buy one of these it will come with all the extra stuff that I don't need.  Also - is it possible to buy one where the bulb itself can be replaced (say a GU10 or whatever)?

Thanks

[image: Bathroom LED Downlight]

Comment: Can you find a manufacturers name and contact them with a model number? perhaps https://www.emcogroup.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=10024

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up using.  I got them at a store in the UK called ToolStation.

[image: IP65 Downlight]

Here are the contents of the box.  The only thing  I needed was the light itself (lower left); all of the other stuff is waste.
[image]